# Sqlite fetch assoc in java/android similar to php?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make SELECT * FROM my table and i don't want to sync colnames with colindex.

Is there a built-in way to fetch column names onto Cursor with columnNames instead of columnIndexes?

So i can use `cursor.getStringForColumnName("name");` instead of knowing that 4th column is "name" column and using `cursor.getString(4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you want to use coulmn name in Cursor. You can actually use `getColumnIndex(String columnName)` to get the index automatically using column name. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29). Then you can continue with the operations. This way you don't need to remember the indexes. hope this helps else please comment.

Comment: Does getColumnIndex makes a query to fetch the information of table to find columnnames and their corresponding ids? I don't want to have performance issues if possible.

Comment: I suppose that you are worried if it is same as querying the table, then getting the column names and mapping it to the indexes? I strongly feel it is not the same. It is not a custom function but has been provided in the Android API itself. Hope you checked the link. So, I don't think it will cause performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

well, YES you can use **PRAGMA  query** for this purpose

Here, is an example

```
 Cursor ti = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(mytable)", null);
    if ( ti.moveToFirst() ) {
        do {
            System.out.println("col: " + ti.getString(1));
        } while (ti.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("name"));
```